# Spring data mongo - how to create an index for a specific collection?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, indexing, spring-data

**Is there a way to create an index in Spring data for a specific collection**?

My problem is that I have a class that is used in different collections, and when I'm trying to add an index to one of the fields (by adding CompoundIndex annotation), the index is created for all of the collections.

The index that I'm trying to create is unique and case insensitive.

Comment: You can use the `org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.index.Indexed` annotation on the mapped POJO's property.

Comment: @prasad_ the problem is that the POJO is used in other POJOs, as a result, the index is added to different collections.

Comment: You can us MongoDB Java Driver collection class methods to create the index directly on the collection: https://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/4.2/apidocs/mongodb-driver-sync/com/mongodb/client/MongoCollection.html

Comment: That's what I did eventually, but the code is ugly...
Is there a way to listen to an event when the Collection is created for the first time?

Comment: You can post the index create code, may be it can be improved upon. _" Is there a way to listen to an event when the Collection is created for the first time?"_ I think, no. But _Change Streams_ listens to create/update/delete operations on the collections _and_some operations on database level.